# How to get value of text box from 1 aspx page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am doing a project on c#.net using sql server 2005.

I have a login.aspx and homepage.aspx. I want to save value of textbox "username" from login.aspx and want it to be displayed on homepage.aspx using label control.

Also, I am using .net's inbuilt login control and dont know how to access the database/table created automatically by .net. So will you also tell me that?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the asp.net login system then you can use the `<asp:LoginName />` control:

- http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+loginname

If you want to access this information via code you can use:

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I tried but it's showing my full pc name PC-3228713E6986\Nikhil instead of username.

Comment: That is your windows login domain and username. I think you have `<authentication mode="Windows" /> ` in your web.config when you should have `<authentication mode="Forms" />` http://www.vpsw.com/blogbaby/CategoryView,category,Authentication.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the built in features, you can access the user's name with context.user.identity.name

To store a value so that other pages can access it, you can use Session("username") = txtLogin.Text

Session variables can be accessed by any page while the user's session is active.